# how to pass multi value query params in swagger

Tags: ruby, swagger

I have following service in swagger.yml. The service is written so that page_id can be passed multiple times. e.g `/pages?page_id[]=123&page_id[]=542`

I checked this link https://swagger.io/specification/ but couldnt understand how could i update yml so i could pass id multiple times.

I see that i have to set `collectionFormat` but dont know how.

I tried updating it like below but no luck https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md.

it generates url like 'http://localhost:0000/pages?page_id=123%2C%20542`

```
 '/pages':
    get:
      tags:
        - 
      summary: get the list of pages
      operationId: getPages
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: page_id
          in: query
          description: some description
          required: false
          type: string
          collectionFormat: multi
        - name: page_detail
          in: query
          description: some description
          required: false
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
        '401':
          description: Authentication Failed
        '404':
          description: Not Found
        '503':
          description: Service Not Available
```

Comment: Those who are looking for the OpenAPI 3 format can find the answer in the https://stackoverflow.com/q/62527254/355438 question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are almost there. Name the parameter `page_id[]`, make it `type: array` and use `collectionFormat: multi`:

```
      parameters:
        - name: page_id[]
          in: query
          description: some description
          required: false
          type: array
          items:
            type: string   # or type: integer or whatever the type is 
          collectionFormat: multi
```

Note that the requests will be sent with the `[` and `]` characters percent-encoded as `%5B` and `%5D`, because they are reserved characters according to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2).

```
http://example.com/pages?page_id%5B%5D=123&page_id%5B%5D=456
```

Comment: one question, when i try to pass a blank value for page_id it doesnt return data for blank value. do you know why? `?page_id[]=def&page_id[]=%22%20%22`

Comment: @mike `%22%20%22` is not really a "blank" value, it's `" "` (space inside quotes) - is this a valid value that your server expects?

Comment: Yes page_id can also be empty, hence passed `" "`.

Comment: It probably depends on how the server is implemented - does it expect `page_id[]=" "` or maybe `page_id[]=` (no value)? If you wrote the server, look into your code. If it's a third-party API, check its documentation.

Answer (score 5):

From the docs:

```
parameters:
- name: id
  in: path
  description: ID of pet to use
  required: true
  schema:
    type: array
    style: simple
    items:
      type: string
```

You have to define the parameter as array.

Comment: Which docs? It's not clear which version you're referring to. Please provide a link.

Answer (score 1):

How to add default values to the query parameter of the type array:

```
    parameters:
      - name: 'liabilityType[]'
        in: query
        description: liabilityType filters the servicers list according to liability types.
        required: false
        schema:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
        collectionFormat: multi
        value:
          - CAR
          - HOUSE
```

I have attached a picture of how this code would look in the Swagger UI

[image: image1]