# How does open api 3.0 support a single query param key with multiple values?

Tags: swagger, openapi

For an api with this format: `GET /resource?param=value1&param=value2&param=value3`
In open Api 2.0, we can specify like this:

```
parameters:
    - in: query
      name: color
      type: array
      collectionFormat: multi
      items:
        type: string
```

But in v3.0 attribute collectionFormat is not available. So while trying with collectionFormat, I received error saying  `should not have additional property: collectionFormat`.

I have searched the documentation but can't find any answer. Does anyone have any idea what should be the new implementation to migrate from 2.0 to 3.0 version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `style` and `explode` properties instead:

```
  - name: param
    in: query
    description: Id description
    required: false
    style: form
    explode: true
    schema:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
```

where

- `explode: true` will form param=abc&param=xyz etc
  and
- `explode: false` will form param=abc,xyz

References:

- Detailed description with examples from the [Swagger's OpenAPI Guide](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#query)
- Parameter [style
  values](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/latest.html#style-values) with
  [examples](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/latest.html#style-examples)
  in the OpenAPI 3 specification
- [Corresponding section](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/#array) in the OpenAPI 2 specification (describes the `collectionFormat` property, which has been replaced in the new version of the specification by the `style` property)

Comment: explode (true/false) specifies whether arrays and objects should generate separate parameters for each array item or object property. You can check this concept from the schema vs content section of this [page](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#schema-vs-content).

Comment: why there is no explode=both ? spring mvc supports both types.