# Swagger: cannot set "collectionFormat"

Tags: swagger, openapi

A JSON query should be usable with multiple search parameters. For this, the server needs to get each parameter as search object, for example:

```
url/search=FirstParameter[EQ]foo&search=SecondParameter[EQ]bar
```

We use the following declaration in swagger:

```
 parameters:
searchParam:
  description: |
    array of strings like e.g. person.nameLast[\<operand>]Bur<br>
    \<operands> \:= LEQ, LT, EQ, GT, GEQ, LIKE
  name: search
  in: query
  schema:
    type: array
    writeOnly: true
    items:
      minItems: 1
      type: string
```

The issue is, that the PHP library generated from swagger creates requests like this:

```
url/search=FirstParameter[EQ]foo&SecondParameter[EQ]bar
```

Which is not usable by server. To address this issue, i found that you could influence this behavior by setting the attribute "collectionFormat" not to multi but to csv.

My issue is, that declarations taken from the example page
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/

do not work and display error:

> should NOT have additional properties additionalProperty: collectionFormat

I've tried:

```
parameters:
searchParam:
  description: |
    array of strings like e.g. person.nameLast[\<operand>]Bur<br>
    \<operands> \:= LEQ, LT, EQ, GT, GEQ, LIKE
  name: search
  in: query
  schema:
    type: array
    collectionFormat: csv
    writeOnly: true
    items:
      minItems: 1
      type: string
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Which program/library gives you this error message? Might be relevant info so we can figure out what the reason by this error message is

Comment: the swagger hub webpage where you can edit the parameters

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How does OpenAPI 3.0 support a single query param key with multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62527254/113116)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`collectionFormat` is an OpenAPI 2.0 keyword (i.e. used in `swagger: "2.0"`), but you seem to be using OpenAPI 3.0 (`openapi: 3.0.x`). The corresponding OAS3 keywords are [`style`](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3.html#parameterStyle) and [`explode`](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3.html#parameterExplode), see the [Parameter Serialization](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/) guide for details.

Try the following:

```yaml
paths:
  /url:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: search
          description: |-
            An array of strings like e.g. `person.nameLast[<operand>]value`
            
            &lt;operand> can be: LEQ, LT, EQ, GT, GEQ, LIKE

          schema:
            type: array
            minItems: 1   # This keyword must be on the same level as `type: array`
            items:
              type: string

          # Optional example
          example:
            - FirstParameter[EQ]foo
            - SecondParameter[EQ]bar

          # This is the default serialization style for query parameters
          # so you can omit these keywords if you wish
          style: form
          explode: true
```

Note that the requests will be sent with the `[` and `]` characters percent-encoded as `%5B` and `%5D`, because they are reserved characters according to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2).

```
url?search=FirstParameter%5BEQ%5Dfoo
```

The backend server is supposed to decode `%5B...%5D` back to `[...]`. (Any RFC-compliant server should do this automatically.)