# Swagger UI input set of variables

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I create an swagger API as below
[image]

However, I am blocked to input set of UUID through swagger UI without any reason. It seems that I don't input in correct format (""","" or ["",""] )

[image]

May I know how to input correct set of UUID or other suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: The parameter in Swagger UI expects a single UUID without quotes. This means the Java annotations are wrong - they generate a single-value parameter instead of an array parameter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62527254/how-does-open-api-3-0-support-a-single-query-param-key-with-multiple-values

The limitation seems comes from the swagger3 UI single query design and it doesn't support the multiple value in the single query.